# Enumerating group memberships of AD users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My boss wants to know group membership of AD users in the company.
I have 3000+ users account to manage.

I wanted to write a bit of PowerShell code to get this, but without success.

I'd like to input user list from a .csv file. Its format is:

```
logindid
first.user
second.user
third.user
```

Code I currently have:

```
$path = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

foreach ($UserName in (Import-CSV -Delimiter "`t" -Path $path\users.csv)) {
    $strUserName = Get-ADUser -Filter 'SamAccountName -like "$username.loginid"' |
                   Select-Object Name, SamAccountName
    Add-Content -Path $path\Inventaire.txt -Value $UserName
    $StrUser = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $strUserName |
               select Name >> $path\Inventaire.txt
    $StrUser.MemberOf >> $path\Inventaire.txt
}
```

I'm trying to get a list of my AD users and which group they are member of (from the `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` cmdlet). However, it seems the `$strUserName` variable is empty.

Comment: What is the question? Please elaborate on "without success" - what are you *expecting*, what *actually* happens and what have you done to troubleshoot this on your own

Comment: I added an answer to the duplicate linked by Ansgar. In application to your question, change your Get-ADUser line to `Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '$($username.loginid)'"` (Assuming that your csv uses `loginid` not `logindid`)

Comment: Alas, always the same result.
I think that it could be : Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : Cannot validate argument on parameter: 'Identity'. The argument is null or empty.

I set a Breakpoint to check the value of $strUserName and it seems to be actually empty ...